# jQuery call function outside of defined plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey all I have the following jQuery code that I am using for a tooltip type of thing:

```
$(function () {
    /* popModal */
    $('#pop-overlay').on('click', function () {
        popModalClose();
    });

    (function ($) {        
        $.fn.popModal = function (method) {
            var elem                    = $(this),
            [ect,......etc...]
        function popModalClose() {
            elemObj = $('div[' + elemData + ']');
            elem.removeAttr(elemData + '_id');                
            $('[data-item-id="' + elem.attr('data-item-id') + '"]').css({ 'z-index': '50' });
            $('#currentUsers').select3({ showDropdown: true });

            if (elemObj.length) {
                reverseEffect();
                $('.' + elemClass + '_source').replaceWith($('.' + elemClass + '_content').children());
                elemObj.remove();
                $('html.' + elemClass + 'Open').off('.' + elemClass + 'Event').removeClass(elemClass + 'Open'); 
                $('#pop-overlay').clearQueue().stop().fadeOut('slow');
                clickedAlready = false;
            }
        }
        [ect,......etc...]
     };
   })(jQuery);
});
```

What I am wanting to do is call the **popModalClose** when I click on the overlay that's called **pop-overlay**.

Currently, using the code above, it gives me an error that it can not find the function **popModalClose()**.

Ive tried:

```
$.fn.popModal.popModalClose();
$.fn.popModalClose();
$popModal.popModalClose();
$popModalClose();
$.popModal.popModalClose();
```

Comment: You can't call it directly unless the plugin provides a method to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has a `hide` method that calls `popModalClose`:

```
$('html').popModal("hide");
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help Barmar!